# How to simulate a click on a @Html.ActionLink in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this part of view :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.listeStations){
   <tbody>
       <tr id="ligneRecherche">
           <td id="tdId">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nom)
           </td>
           <td id="tdData">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.adr)
           </td>
           <td id="tdLangue">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cp)
           </td>
           <td id="tdType">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ville)
           </td>
           <td id="selection">
               @Html.ActionLink("Choisir", "DetailsStation", new { id=item.id })
           </td>
       </tr> 
   </tbody>
}
</table>
```

If one user click everywhere on one row of the table it performs the actionLink. It's possible to do that in JS or other ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `class` to your `tr` tag to select it with jquery.

```
<tr id="ligneRecherche" class="row">
```

and select clicked row with using jquery

```
$(".row").click(function(){
    var url = $('td a', this).attr('href');
    window.location = url;
});
```

And also your view should look like this: (remove `tbody` tag to out of `foreach`)

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.listeStations){
   <tr id="ligneRecherche" class="row">
       <td id="tdId">
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nom)
       </td>
       <td id="tdData">
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.adr)
       </td>
       <td id="tdLangue">
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cp)
       </td>
       <td id="tdType">
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ville)
       </td>
       <td id="selection">
           @Html.ActionLink("Choisir", "DetailsStation", new { id=item.id })
       </td>
   </tr> 
}
</tbody>
```

one more info: `id` of `tr` and `td` tags are meaningless. because they are repeatitive elements.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I have this exception : the ressource is not found. Requested URL: / Home / undefined

Comment: your action url is not correct, or you dont have `DetailsStation/Choisir`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi Your answer in not correct here: `$(this).closest("a").attr("href")`